# Where are the files generated through code in a kaggle kernel stored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kaggle

Generated a few csv files in kaggle using np.savetxt, but can't find them. The workspace just shows the dataset that I am working on.

`np.savetxt("user64.txt", user64[cols], fmt = '%f', delimiter = ',')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/58426

Pretty simple and posted from Kaggle forum.